# How to create an Array that contains images in java?

Tags: java, arrays, image, nullpointerexception

I need to create an array of images. when I try to do the `getGraphics` method of the Graphics class to access the Image I created in the array index it throws the java.lang.NullPointerException error even though a few lines above I created the image in that index

I tried changing the index and changing the condition of the foor loop, but it still enters the loop only once and says that the array in index 0 is null.

```
private Image[] frames = new Image[100];
for (int index = 0; index < frames.length; index++){
        if (frames[index] == null) 
        {
            frames[index] = this.createImage(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        }

        Graphics graphic = frames[index].getGraphics();
```

I expect the array to be full of images at the end, in order to paint them and finish the job.

Comment: paste `createImage(w, h)` method will help

Comment: @QingfeiYuan It is presumably createImage from java.awt.Component.

Comment: What is the context in which you're calling this? Are you inside a component of some kind? What kind? Has it been added to a container? Has that container been shown on the screen?

Comment: In any case, `createImage` only works once the component is displayable. If you want an image you can draw on outside of that context, try `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use following code:

ArrayList array = new ArrayList ();

and you can add Image like this:

array.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file_path"));
//there is many Prototypes for decodeFile

then you can use Bitmap like this:

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
image.seImageBitmap(array.get(0));

Comment: OP said array, not ArrayList.

Comment: use : Bitmap[] array = new Bitmap[100];